# Adding new column while CREATE TABLE event trigger fired

Tags: postgresql

**The goal :**

Adding some columns and constraints while creating some tables when the table name begin by "T_R_..."

**The code :**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION complete_table()
  RETURNS event_trigger 
AS 
$$
DECLARE
  alter_query TEXT;
  r RECORD;
BEGIN
  IF tg_tag = 'CREATE TABLE'
  THEN
    r := pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands();
    IF r.object_identity LIKE '%.T?_R?_%' ESCAPE '?'
    THEN
       alter_query = format('ALTER TABLE %s ADD %s_CODE CHAR(16) CONSTRAINT UK_%S_CODE UNIQUE;',
                          r.object_identity, RIGHT(r.object_identity, 3), RIGHT(r.object_identity, 3));
       EXECUTE alter_query;
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

For the "procedure"... ANd now the trigger :

```
CREATE EVENT TRIGGER catch_table
   ON ddl_command_end 
   EXECUTE PROCEDURE complete_table();
```

And finally the test :

```
CREATE TABLE public.T_R_ABC (ABC_ID INT PRIMARY KEY);
```

Now, the trouble :

*ERROR:  ERREUR:  la requête « SELECT pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands() » a renvoyé plus d'une ligne
CONTEXT:  fonction PL/pgSQL complete_table(), ligne 8 à affectation*

Which in english is something like : The query ... returns more than one row ... line 8 when affecting

Answer (score 3):

The function pg_event_trigger_dll_commands() returns several rows: the table itself and the index. You are getting the error that you're getting because you're attempting to assign several rows to a single record. You need to iterate through them and check to make sure you're looking at object_type = 'table'. Also the check for the start of the table name should be case insensitive (ILIKE vs LIKE) and within the format function UK_%S_CODE needs to be UK_%s_CODE (lowercase s):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION complete_table()
 RETURNS event_trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    alter_query TEXT;
    r RECORD;
BEGIN
    IF tg_tag = 'CREATE TABLE'
    THEN
        FOR r IN SELECT * FROM pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()
        LOOP       
            IF r.object_type = 'table' and r.object_identity ILIKE '%.T?_R?_%' ESCAPE '?'
            THEN
                alter_query = format('ALTER TABLE %s ADD %s_CODE CHAR(16) CONSTRAINT UK_%s_CODE UNIQUE;',
                      r.object_identity, RIGHT(r.object_identity, 3), RIGHT(r.object_identity, 3));       
                EXECUTE alter_query;
            END IF;
       END LOOP;
    END IF;
END;
$function$;
```